# want to count characters on load window

Tags: javascript

I have a function counting characters correctly.. on key up and key down eventes

but i am echoing the value from the database so when the page will load there will already be some text on load window. I am not able to count the character as soon as page loads. Can any one help me out ?

Here is my javascript that deals with character count limit is 50

```
function textCounter(textField, showCountField) {
    var maxAmount = 50;
    if (textField.value.length > maxAmount) {
    textField.value = textField.value.substring(0, maxAmount);
    } else { 
     showCountField.value = maxAmount - textField.value.length;
    }
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: use `window.load = function() { textCounter(document.getElementById( textfield), document.getElementById( showCountFieldID) ); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
window.load = function() { 
   textCounter(document.getElementById( textfieldId), document.getElementById( showCountFieldID) ); 
}
```

Comment: do i have do define whole function below the second line ?

Comment: no, just call the function with their corresponding parameter

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<body onload "textCounter(par1,par2)"> // replace with pweameters
```